# Как удалить сообщение что человек вступил по ссылке приглашению?

Tags: python, aiogram

Этот код удаляет сообщение о вступлении и выхода человека из группы, однако если юзер вступил в группу по приглашению, то это сообщение он не удаляет.
В документации тоже вроде бы нету такого.
Как решить эту проблему?

```
 @dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
 async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
     await message.delete()
```